# Exporting global declaration breaks existing custom module declarations

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, node-modules, es6-modules

In my NextJS web app, I have an existing set of custom typings for packages I've installed that do not have types available. I needed to extend my `window` with a module from a third party script.

So I extended and exported the `Window` interface in my `global.d.ts` file. Once I did that, one of the packages that I've declared `any` types globally for started giving me the infamous `Could not find a declaration file for module but it exists (TS7016)` error. When I removed the new export of the new global `window` type, `TS7016` went away`.

How can I have both custom typings for 3rd party modules along with a exported custom global type?

```
// global.d.ts
declare module '@package-maintainer/*';
declare module '@package-maintainer-2/*';
declare module 'some-package';
declare module 'some-package-2';

export declare global {
  interface Window {
    thirdPartyModule: {
      aMethod: () => void
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a handful of testing, what I believe the issue was was the exporting of a module, which turned the `global.d.ts` file itself into a module, and that is not compatible with `declare module`. I'm not exactly sure the reasoning behind this. I'd have to dig into this further.

The solution here was to separate the custom type definitions into two files, one for global definitions and one for module definitions:

```
// global.d.ts
export declare global {
  interface Window {
    thirdPartyModule: {
      aMethod: () => void
    };
  }
}
```

```
// modules.d.ts
declare module '@package-maintainer/*';
declare module '@package-maintainer-2/*';
declare module 'some-package';
declare module 'some-package-2';
```

With these separated, but both included in my `tsconfig`, I was able to extend my `window` object and keep my custom coercion to `any` for my third-party packages.